# Sqlite error while creating a rails project on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

Im a newbee to rails. 
Im trying to create a rails project

`rails new depot`

Unfortunately this is failing at the point where rails try to do geminstall of sqlite

The error is as follows

```
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.0
Installing sqlite3 1.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190205-19788-3qr0ge.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3

C:\Users\rose\railsprojects>
```

I have installed (copied binaries) from SQLite Download page to my C:\sqlite folder. 
My OS is 64 bit so I have downloaded "sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3260000.zip" and "sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3260000.zip" (from here https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
I also have the dll and header files as shown

```
02/12/2018  12:38 AM           504,837 shell.c
02/12/2018  12:39 AM           490,496 sqldiff.exe
02/12/2018  12:38 AM         7,770,073 sqlite3.c
02/12/2018  12:26 PM             5,933 sqlite3.def
02/12/2018  12:27 PM         1,878,528 sqlite3.dll
02/12/2018  12:40 AM           911,360 sqlite3.exe
02/12/2018  12:38 AM           556,318 sqlite3.h
02/12/2018  12:38 AM            33,713 sqlite3ext.h
02/12/2018  12:40 AM         2,003,968 sqlite3_analyzer.exe
```

Because of this error I tried to install sqlite3 with gem command
As my header and DLL are in directory C:\sqlite, I used the following command on msys2 terminal

```
ridk enable
C:\Users\rose>gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=C:\sqlite
Fetching: sqlite3-1.4.0.gem (100%)
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-dir=C:\sqlite'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190205-17968-rk6pw2.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir=C:\sqlite
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

C:\Users\rose>
```

Any clue whats missing?

The mkmf log says

```
"pkg-config --exists sqlite3"
| pkg-config --libs sqlite3
=> "-LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib -lsqlite3\n"
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby25-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s     -lx64-msvcrt-ruby250  -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby25-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s     -lx64-msvcrt-ruby250 -LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib -lsqlite3 -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

| pkg-config --cflags-only-I sqlite3
=> "-IC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/include\n"
| pkg-config --cflags-only-other sqlite3
=> "\n"
| pkg-config --libs-only-l sqlite3
=> "-lsqlite3\n"
package configuration for sqlite3
cflags: 
ldflags: -LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib
libs: -lsqlite3

find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -IC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:\sqlite/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe   conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_library: checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -IC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:\sqlite/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby25-x64/lib -LC:\sqlite/lib -L. -pipe -s -LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib     -lsqlite3 -lx64-msvcrt-ruby250 -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'pthread_create' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'rb_thread_create'?
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))pthread_create; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                         rb_thread_create
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))pthread_create; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -IC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:\sqlite/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby25-x64/lib -LC:\sqlite/lib -L. -pipe -s -LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib     -lsqlite3 -lx64-msvcrt-ruby250 -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void pthread_create();
17: int t(void) { pthread_create(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for -ldl... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -IC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:\sqlite/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby25-x64/lib -LC:\sqlite/lib -L. -pipe -s -LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib    -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lx64-msvcrt-ruby250 -ldl -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: 
17: int t(void) { ; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for dlopen()... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -IC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:\sqlite/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby25-x64/lib -LC:\sqlite/lib -L. -pipe -s -LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib    -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lx64-msvcrt-ruby250 -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'dlopen' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean '_lopen'?
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))dlopen; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~
                                                         _lopen
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))dlopen; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -IC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:\sqlite/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby25-x64/lib -LC:\sqlite/lib -L. -pipe -s -LC:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib    -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lx64-msvcrt-ruby250 -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:\Users\Navarose\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNQH25m.o:conftest.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void dlopen();
17: int t(void) { dlopen(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

As a last resort I built the SQlite using mingw64
Later tried to install the gem. And a new error which is like shostopper

```
gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=C:\sqlite\ --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\sqlite\.libs\

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190205-18436-ve1008.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-include=C:\sqlite\ --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\sqlite\.libs\
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... no
checking for main() in -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3):

Found a very neat fix in here

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/248

It seesms it is only missing a library in msys2.

`ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn`

After that, the compilation went ok.

`gem install sqlite3 -v 1.4.0`

Note:- adding a dependency on a git branch does not seem ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Point to the fork of `sqlite3-ruby` gem and use the branch last updated in 2018:

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

to your Gemfile. So far, it worked for me. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post it seems like sqlite is not properly installed on your machine including all headers required.

Run the below mentioned command to get it installed properly:

```
gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=C:/path/to/sqlite3
```

Where `C:/path/to/sqlite3` is where the headers (`include`) and libs (`lib`) for sqlite3 are resided.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunatley that didnt work. I have updates the error in original post

Comment: Im really at a blocker point here.. Tried everything from web articles nothing is working. I wonder why well know book Agile Web Development Using Rails 5 by Sam Ruby had ever chosen SQLite as there db of choice. Nothing is there in the book regarding installation. Shame :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's an simple Permission issue, follow the below steps.

1. Uninstall Ruby
2. Reinstall Ruby , **while reinstalling Ruby install it under C:\user-name**  Folder.
3. After Installing Ruby , re run gem install sqllite3 under C:\user-name\    Folder.
   here user-name is user your user directory.
   Example :C:\Users\rose\